# EF6.1 enable-migrations does not work

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have an existing local database and a single DbContext instance in my data (EF 6.1.3) class project. I would like to make this current schema as the initial schema. When I run this command:

```
enable-migrations
```

A folder Migrations and class named Configuration (of type MyProject.Data.Migrations.Configuration) have been created in class project MyProject.Data (as it should). Still, I receive next error in the console window:

```
The migrations configuration type 'MyProject.Data.Migrations.Configuration' was not be found in the assembly 'MyProject.Data'.
```

What is weird is that is is located in this project, with the exact same namespace. What I could mention as a specific implementation, is that my DbContext is not referring to a connection string in app config file, it has private constructors, and it receives a connection string through a static Create method, from custom application configuration file.

```
public MyEntities : DbContext
{
    private ctor(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { ... }

    public static MyEntities Create(string connectionString)
    {
        return new MyEntities(connectionString);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why is this happening? I am unable to move to next step and add initial configuration migration.

Comment: Have you selected the correct default project in the package manager console?

Comment: @jrummell Yes, I have, and as I said, the Configuration class is located in correct project. However, command line does not find it for some reason. One would think if it has added configuration file, it would also find it to that same location, but it doesn't.

Comment: You may need to add a public default constructor.

Comment: Try specifying the project explicitly: -ProjectName MyProject.Data https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/

Comment: @jrummell It needs to have a public parameterless constructor and a name to AppConfig connectionString, so it knows how to connect to database. I will ned to revisit my design to use AppConfig to store connection string, and not in my custom application configuration file. If you post this as answer, I will accept your suggestion.

Comment: Glad it worked! I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Migrations needs to be able to create an instance of your DbContext. Add a public default constructor. By default it looks for a connection string in your startup project's configuration file with the same name as your context. You can change that by calling `base()` with a different connection string name.

```
public MyEntities : DbContext
{
    public MyEntities () : base("DefaultConnection") {}
}
```